# Generically extract a value from typed Record

Tags: typescript, type-inference, fp-ts

I am using fp-ts and in this case, Options.
Lets say I have an example type:

```
import * as O from 'fp-ts/Option';

type ExampleType = {
  a: number,
  b: O.Option<number>,
  c: O.Option<string>
}
```

and a record of these types:

```
type ExampleRecord = Record<string, ExampleType>
```

I have discovered the same "theme" several times:
I want to write a generic function that can, given a property name and the record type (which can be ExampleType or any other type with at least an option property), turns this:

```
const a: ExampleRecord = { key1: {a: 1, b: O.none, c: O.some('example')}, key2: { a: 2, b: O.some(3), c: O.none } }
```

into this:

```
const b = f('b', a) // b is { key2: { a: 2, b: 3, c: O.none } }
```

Notice I give it the b key and it filters all records that have no value for b, while extracting the value from the option in case it exists and returning it.

However, I have no idea how to type such a function f without losing the type information. The return type should be something like this:

```
type TheReturnType = Record<string, ExampleType & {b: number}>
```

But I fail to figure out how to infer this dynamically if it is even possible. I mean, the b: number comes from the fact that b is an O.Option in T, but as b is dynamic, that makes it harder to actually infer anything.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the type of the option using a conditional type. You can then use a generic function to capture the type of the record type (lets call it `T`), and the type of the key (lets call it `K`). With this information you can then create the required type, by omitting `K` from `T` and intersecting it with the an object type that contains just `K` with the type of the option:

```
const a: ExampleRecord = { key1: { a: 1, b: O.none, c: O.some('example') }, key2: { a: 2, b: O.some(3), c: O.none } }

type OptionValue<T extends O.Option<any>> = T extends O.Some<infer U>  ? U: never;

function f<T extends Record<K, O.Option<any>>, K extends keyof T>(key: K, value: Record<string, T>): Record<string, Omit<T, K> & Record<K, OptionValue<T[K]>>> {
  return null!;
}

const b = f('b', a) // b is { key2: { a: 2, b: 3, c: O.none } 
b["key2"].b.toExponential // number
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwtgDg9gTgLgAgN4KhOIoDsEEMDOCA8ggL4IBmMUYCA5BRALRz53AfBwCeEApggCiAD1yQANnwAqvAQF5kwBHgBcCLAFcwAIz4wANEoTa1RAHRF0mLAB5NOvQD5DygMamLV7DfxwYILABzR2BSDh5+IVEJPgAlPldYABMEBXjEmCSfPwDA-SixCEkZfhDgRKxfVQKY9OTU5AQAaz5uAEY1FFw1NvyTYjMsbD589wH8Gj4ACjo+aKK+OgBKMnyW7gAmTuqNvo8JsGmAZiXRjyGsAXIwrlliLywANVxxDT4bKQQ5uD4sJMJzJYMN5cFhuI5HA1Pt9fv8BgBlSY2AIUPQIACqkIQAH4MWpLgA3PQAbg4FA0WFcwJwFA+X2EPz+hDqmRsAGl8oCHjZQeDnAg2fTGXD1lAKAgpI4pus1ByEASXm81Cysr5-EF8pKlsqEslsuq8sQwCA4B98mzIQAyBAq9mch7PV7vKQAbTZAF0IZCkEYYHw4BoYDhNOJxABCUk3CpVbQNCgzbR0fK4FYAelTxgQIEIKHWW0a3QQu2MaiOZwGFyuCGA2hdACI83X3WZtGY4FARNBLlgMC8EOn1FpdDBgEA)

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked very well! I had experimented with similar things, but couldn't get it to work. The idea of Record<K, something> is also new to me, I can restrict the records that way, good to know!